# H2 Console not working on Void Linux, works on Windows

Tags: linux, spring-boot, localhost, h2

Basically, I have a basic SpringBoot application with implemented H2 database. Everything works well when trying to access h2-console from Windows, but accessing it from Linux returns 403 error. I do have implemented security in the app itself, but access to h2-console is already permitted there. I also have context-path in the app, but disabling it or changing it didn't work either. Can't grasp if there's an error in the code itself, or is the problem really in using Void Linux.

**WebSecurityConfiguration**:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/login")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); //JWT procesiramo pre autentikacije
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
```

**application.properties**:

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/data/db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
server.error.include-message=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;NON_KEYWORDS=USER
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

**Spring Boot log**:

```
2023-03-21T19:52:52.116+01:00 ERROR 19704 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api]    : Servlet.init() for servlet [jakartaWebServlet] threw exception

org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: SlepiLepi: SlepiLepi: Name or service not known" [90028-214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:387) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:284) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.updateURL(WebServer.java:395) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.init(WebServer.java:374) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet.init(JakartaWebServlet.java:52) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:995) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: SlepiLepi: SlepiLepi: Name or service not known" [90028-214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SlepiLepi: SlepiLepi: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1662) ~[na:na]
        at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:282) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SlepiLepi: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1534) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1524) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1657) ~[na:na]
        ... 24 common frames omitted

2023-03-21T19:52:52.117+01:00 ERROR 19704 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[jakartaWebServlet]      : Allocate exception for servlet [jakartaWebServlet]

java.net.UnknownHostException: SlepiLepi: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1534) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1524) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1657) ~[na:na]
        at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:282) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.updateURL(WebServer.java:395) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.init(WebServer.java:374) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet.init(JakartaWebServlet.java:52) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:995) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-03-21T19:52:52.119+01:00 DEBUG 19704 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-03-21T19:52:52.120+01:00 DEBUG 19704 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-21T19:52:52.120+01:00 DEBUG 19704 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important part of this stack trace is here:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SlepiLepi: SlepiLepi: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1662) ~[na:na]
```

Your system has `SlepiLepi` host name, but doesn't have an IP address for it.

Host name is usually configured in `/etc/hostname`.

IP address for it can be configured in `/etc/hosts`, you can add it do default record with `localhost`:

`127.0.0.1       localhost your_host_name_here`

or you can use a some other address that belongs to your system.

Comment: That was the issue, everything works now. It didn't make much sense to me, since using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost didn't work either, so I just ignored the idea that it was a 'hosts' issue.